# MySQL trigger: how to throw an error when condition is not met

Tags: mysql, triggers

DB schema:

```
book(bno,title, author,year,press,price,total,stock)

borrow(cno,bno,borrow_data,return_date)
```

Sample data in book table:
1   Database System Concepts  Abraham  2011  McGrawHill  99.00  5  4
2   Modern Operating Systems  Andrew   2011  Pearson     75.00  3  1
4   Computer Network          Tanenbaum 2000 Pearson     58.00  4  3\

Sample data in borrow table:
1   1   2018-01-01  2018-01-14
1   2   2018-01-06  2018-01-10
2   2   2018-02-03  2018-02-08
3   4   2018-02-05  2018-03-01

SQL to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE book (bno INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                   title VARCHAR(100),
                   author VARCHAR(40),
                   year YEAR,
                   press VARCHAR(60),
                   price DECIMAL(6,2),
                   total INT CHECK ((total >= 0)),
                   stock INT CHECK ((stock >= 0)),
                   PRIMARY KEY (bno));

CREATE TABLE borrow (cno INT,
                     bno INT,
                     borrow_date DATE,
                     return_date DATE,
                     CHECK (borrow_date < return_date));

INSERT INTO book
VALUES (1,'Database System Concepts','Abraham',2011,'McGrawHill',99.00,5,4),
       (2,'Modern Operating Systems','Andrew',2009,'Pearson',75.00,3,1),
       (3,'Computer Network','Tanenbaum',2000,'Pearson',58.00,4,3);
   
INSERT INTO borrow
VALUES (1,1,'2018-1-1','2018-1-14'),
       (1,2,'2018-1-6','2018-1-10'),
       (2,2,'2018-2-3','2018-2-8'),
       (3,3,'2018-2-5','2018-3-1');
```

Requirement:
When inserting a new record to borrow table, check if bno exists in book and if stock is greater than 0, if so, update the stock in book table by stock-1 and finish the insert operation; else throw an error

I am not sure why it doesn't work with my code.
Any help would be appreciated!!

```
CREATE TRIGGER borrow_insert_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON borrow
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT bno 
             FROM book
             WHERE NEW.bno = book.bno) 
  AND (SELECT stock
       FROM book
       WHERE NEW.bno = book.bno)>0
  THEN UPDATE book
       SET stock = stock-1
       WHERE NEW.bno = book.bno
  ELSE SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
       SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Book doesn\'t exist or out of stock'
  END IF
END;

The error:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ELSE SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
   SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Book doesn\'t exist or o' at line 14
```

Comment: Incorrect ideology. You must not decrease `stock` but count the amount of borrowed books and compare it with existing books amount. *how to throw an error when condition is not met* See [SIGNAL Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html) PS. When the borrowed book is returned does you delete the row from borrow table?

Comment: *I am not sure why it doesn't work with my code.* It is synthactically wrong. See error message while execute this script.

Comment: [**Please Never** post images of code, data or error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2310830). Please edit your question and include copy/paste the text into the question, formatted. 
This is so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: Start an SQL question by showing the schema for all the relevant tables. An example of the data contained in these tables is also very useful. If at all possible create a SQLFiddle with the schema defined and some test data provided

Comment: @Akina **stock** represents the remaining amount of the book, and I have another attribute **total** for the total amount. The error message said something wrong around ELSE SIGNAL SQLSTATE line, but I can't figure it out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you have seen an error message, please include the complete error message in your question. Help us to help you!

Comment: @BillKarwin I have included the error in my question and added some data. It's the first time I posted a question so really sorry for some unclear points. Again, thanks for you suggestion!

Comment: @RiggsFolly Many thanks for your suggestion! I have modified my question.

Answer (score 3):

You must use a semicolon (`;`) to terminate each statement in the body of your trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER borrow_insert_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON borrow
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF EXISTS (SELECT bno
             FROM book
             WHERE NEW.bno = book.bno)
  AND (SELECT stock
       FROM book
       WHERE NEW.bno = book.bno)>0
  THEN UPDATE book
       SET stock = stock-1
       WHERE NEW.bno = book.bno;
                               ^ here
  ELSE SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
       SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Book doesn\'t exist or out of stock';
                                                               ^ here
  END IF;
        ^ here, because IF/THEN/ELSE/END IF counts as a compound statement
END;
```

Terminating statements even within blocks of code is a common feature of many programming languages, such as C, Java, PHP, etc.

You should read the MySQL manual about compound statement syntax, especially this page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/begin-end.html

Comment: Thank you! I tried as you suggested, but it shows: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 13; You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ELSE SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Book doesn\'t exist or o' at line 1; You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF' at line

Comment: Well, you're going to have to learn to use syntax reference documentation. I gave you the link to the manual. Please start studying that page, and also read related pages. You are not going to get far as a programmer without doing a lot of reading. That's how I learned, and most other professional programmers.

Comment: Yeah I went through the documentation and found my error. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Good job! That's a skill that will allow you to work more effectively and independently.